# Can I make the journal screen show only incomplete missions?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Mass Effect 3, I often find myself looking at the Journal screen to see what missions I have to do, and what systems I have to go to to do them. However, every time I look it seems to start in the middle of the list of completed missions and I have to scroll up to see the incomplete missions. This gets really annoying after doing it a few times. Is there a way to make the list only show incomplete missions or at least start with them on the screen when I open the Journal?

Comment: Unfortunately, the journal defaulting to the mission *Citadel: Improved Power Grid* after completion is a [known bug](http://social.bioware.com/%2525C2%2525A0social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/345/index/9747489/1). As far as I know, there's no workaround, but as I'm not 100% sure, just leaving a comment.

Comment: @FAE Thanks for that link. I think I found a fix from it.

Answer (score 2):

As FAE pointed out, this is a known bug on the [Bioware forums](http://social.bioware.com/%2525C2%2525A0social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/345/index/9747489/1). As documented there, this problem appears to be a bug caused by the "new" tag to not be removed properly from one of the quests. That means that choosing "mark all as read" should fix the problem. I tested this and now the mission screen starts by showing the top of the list as it should.

**EDIT:** It looks like this fix only works for a very short period of time, and it is not repeatable. A simpler but less effective fix, as mentioned in the linked forum post, is to simply sort by name every time you open the mission screen.

Comment: Sorting is what I've resorted to.  Faster and easier than scrolling up.